# Are invisible supply caravans still shown on the map for opponents?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In World versus World, there is some [Supply Caravans](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Supply_caravan) to defend. Those are Dolyaks transporting supplies for a tower, a keep or Stonemist Castle. When a Supply Caravan is alive on the map, it appears with a Dolyak icon and the color of the team owning it.

[image]

It is possible to hide those Dolyaks by using some skills such as [Shadow Refuge](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Shadow_Refuge). I know that, for the team owning the Dolyak, the icon will remain on the map. But do the two other teams are still able to see this icon while the Dolyak is invisible ?

Comment: This is something I've been wondering for years and keep forgetting to test out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other teams can still see the icon. But not the Dolyak itself.

Comment: Was that something you experienced yourself or an information you found/heard somewhere?

Comment: played WvW for roughly 2.5 years. Tried it a year ago and mate of mine could still see it on the map.

Comment: NP, ye can't really show proof of it, cause it didn't seem like anything special when I tried it. Would be awesome if it did work thought